# Android Developer:: Opening external link within the app

Tags: android, hyperlink, external

Happy Friday to all.

I was wondering if there is a way to open an external link within the app itself? I currently can execute a link, but it opens it in a browser. I would like to open a site or two within the app.

Can this be done?
Oh, please tell me it can be, because this is one of the reasons why I am creating my app in Eclipse instead of Dreamweaver...html can only limit so much stuff!

please and thank you help me figure this out.
Cady

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to use a WebView and load the html into it yourself.

Note that by default a WebView only displays html content. The plugins and javascript are off, and it does not handle link clicks, or forward / backward navigation

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Comment: Oh man! Would this scenario work?

When a user presses Upcoming Events I would like that to open another activity within my app that has live data (from html).

Are you saying that when a user presses webview activity, they will not be able to get back to the main menu?

Comment: because I was using URI and it would state data was loading..but never took me to the external page.  I had two classes...and it just did not work! ):

Comment: They can get back to the main activity with the back button by default. I was referring to the browser forward and back navigation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to open HTML pages inside your app. There's a nice little [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-webview.html) in the docs showing the use of its basic features.

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html), put it in your layout and load URLs to show websites inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done, you can use a [`WebView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) to load the content inside your activity.